# Is batching same functions with SIMD instruction possible?

Tags: gcc, x86, compiler-construction, llvm, simd

I have a scenario that many exact same functions(for simplicity let's just consider C/C++ and python here) will be executed at the same time on my machine. Intuitively I just use multi-threading to treat each instance of a function as a thread to utilize the parallism, they do not contend for same resources but they will do many branch operation(e.g., for loop). However, since they are actually the same functions, I'm thinking about batching them using some SIMD instructions, e.g., AVX-512. Of course, it should be automatic so that users do not have to modify their code.

The reason? Because every thread/process/container/VM occupies resources, but AVX only needs one instructions. So I can hold more users with the same hardware.

Most articles I find online focus on using AVX instructions inside the function, for example, to accelerate the stream data processing, or deal with some large calculation. None of them mentions batching different instances of same function.

I know there are some challenges, such as different execution path caused by different input, and it is not easy to turn a normal function into a batched version automatically, but I think it is indeed possible technically.

Here are my questions

1. Is it hard(or possible) to automatically change a normal function into a batched version?
2. If 1 is no, what restrictions should I put on the function to make it possible? For example, if the function only has one path regardless of the data?
3. Is there other technologies to better solve the problem? I don't think GPU is a good option to me because GPU cannot support IO or branch instruction, although its SIMT fits perfectly into my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSE/AVX is basically a vector unit, it allows simple operations (like +-*/ and,or,XOR etc) on arrays of multiple elements at once.   AVX1 and 2 has 256 byte registers, so you can do e.g. 8 32-bit singles at once, or 4 doubles. AVX-512 is coming but quite rare atm.

So if your functions are all operations on arrays of basic types, it is a natural fit.  Rewriting your function using AVX intrinsics is doable if the operations are very simple. Complex things (like not matching vector widths) or even doing it in assembler is a challenge though.

If your function is not operating on vectors then it becomes difficult, and the possibilities are mostly theoretical. Autovectorizing compilers sometimes can do this, but it s rare and limited, and extremely complex.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is difficult too. I just wonder has anybody tried to explore this direction? That seems intuitive although hard, maybe someone has investigated a little bit about it? But I don't find any online.

Comment: The most common mistake is to consider AVX (processors in their own right. They are more extensions, and for specialistic purposes. You can't optimize _any_ problem with AVX

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the long delay

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to fix this: vectorization (SIMD) and parallelization (threads).

GCC can already do the SIMD vectorization you want provided that the function is inlined, and the types and operations are compatible (and it will automatically inline smallish functions without you asking it to).

E.g.

```
inline void func (int i) {
   somearray[i] = someotherarray[i] * athirdarray[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < ABIGNUMBER; i++)
   func (i);
```

Vectorization and inlining are enabled at `-O3`.

If the functions are too complex, and/or GCC doesn't vectorize it yet, then you can use OpenMP or OpenACC to parallelize it.

OpenMP uses special markup to tell the compiler where to spawn threads.

E.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < ABIGNUMBER; i++)
    ....
```

And yes, you *can* do that on a GPU too! You do have to do a bit more typing to get the data copied in and out correctly. Only the marked up areas run on the GPU. Everything else runs on the CPU, so I/O etc. is not a problem.

```
#pragma omp target map(somearray,someotherarray,athirdarray)
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < ABIGNUMBER; i++)
    ....
```

OpenACC is a similar idea, but more specialized towards GPUs.

You can find OpenMP and OpenACC compilers in many places. Both GCC and LLVM support NVidia GPUs. LLVM has some support for AMD GPUs, and there are unofficial GCC builds available too (with official support coming soon).

Comment: Thanks for the SIMD and omp example, but I think that is a little different from what I need. Let me make my question more clear. Suppose there is a master-worker program, and every time a request comes, master starts a worker to handle it. These workers have exact same code instructions, but with different input data. I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically 'rewrite' the worker code so that I can handle 8 request in one thread or VM instead of starting 8 threads. Whether the worker uses SIMD inside its code or not is not important.

Comment: I don't know of a magic solution. I've written what you describe manually, using state machines. A more modern approach would be to use coroutines. They're planned for C++ but that's about it. I don't know about Python. Honestly, this is the job that Go was created for.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay